# scrollview not working... scrollview works only in half of the screen

Tags: android

Only half of the screen is covered in scrollview and the attributes are reduced to half

[image: Here is the sc of scrollview not working`]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/burn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="270dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="224dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="52dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="224dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
            fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
            fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
            fancy:fb_radius="30dp"
            fancy:fb_text="LOGIN / REGISTER"
            fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>




</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you try to add android:fillViewport="true" to your ScrollView?

Comment: @W0rmH0le thanks that worked but when i run on my phone the login button again comes in the center of edit texts...so unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: @W0rmH0le please help

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the following changes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    **android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

You need to adjust the height of scrollview container (Relative layout in your case) to wrap content and change the viewport to true in the scrollview.

Comment: Easiest solution here, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to put your ScrollView tag in a mother LinearLayout
like :

```
<LinearLayout><scrollView> your stuff </scrollView></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a constraint layout in the scroll view instead of using multiple linear layouts since it would be easier to create the layout. Or optimize the layout to work with one linear layout.

** **Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/burn" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="52dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="224dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="52dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_password" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="224dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                fancy:fb_borderColor="#FFFFFF"
                fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
                fancy:fb_defaultColor="#7ab800"
                fancy:fb_focusColor="#9bd823"
                fancy:fb_iconPosition="left"
                fancy:fb_radius="30dp"
                fancy:fb_text="LOGIN / REGISTER"
                fancy:fb_textColor="#FFFFFF" />
           </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Result**

[image: result]

I can tell you were using extra linear layouts to center items. 
For future reference, **android:gravity** deals with the items inside of the layout and **android:layout_gravity** is the alignment of the layout itself.